How unique is HttpContext's ConnectionInfo ID?
There is an existing cache program that could not be updated. I can pass one unique identifier for a user. Sadly, the existing app doesn't have user session, could I rely on HttpContext.Connection.Id to make sure it is unique per user?

tbh I dont really understand the question but the connection id identifies a unique connection. Usually if you have a web app a connection might be used by multiple users. However if you instantiate a connection with each run (for example a desktop app) it might be unique. Please elaborate on your use case a bit more
